# How to create multiple dataframes from an existing one?

Tags: r

My issue is that after reading a **Json file** and then using `tibble::enframe(unlist(data))`, I want to create multiple dataframes by splitting the existing one at **20th*n, where (n=1,2..nrow(data)/20) rows**. By simply subsetting it, I am getting what I want with `data[1:20,]`. I am also aware of the `split() and slice() functions`. I am wondering how can I come up with multiple dataframes by looping over the initial dataframe. Thnx in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` creating an index of every `n` rows to split the data.

```
n <- 20
df <- data.frame(a = runif(100), b = rnorm(100))
list_df <- split(df, ceiling(seq(nrow(df))/n))
```

To create new dataframes -

```
names(list_df) <- paste0('df', seq_along(list_df))
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hallo Ronak and thanks a lot for your answer. This main issue I have again is that I want to come up with a solution that returns new dataframes. What you proposed to me creates **Large list**, from which I can retrieve every element and then transform it to a dataframe --> `as.data.frame(list_df [1])`. What I want though is to loop through that large list and create the respective dataframes

Comment: See the updated answer to create new dataframes.

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks again for your help. It's highly appreciated!